# Use stored procedure in c# using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm looking for how to use a stored procedure using Linq-to-SQL in C#.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uploadImage] @ppr INT,
    @imagename VARCHAR,
    @imagecontent VARCHAR,
    @imagebinary IMAGE
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT ImageID
        FROM [ImageStorage]
        WHERE ImageID = (
                SELECT codeimg
                FROM Agent
                WHERE PPR = @ppr
                )
        )
BEGIN
    --select ImageBinary from [ImageStorage] where ImageID = ( select codeimg from Agent where PPR=@ppr) 
    UPDATE ImageStorage
    SET ImageName = @imagename,
        ImageContentType = @imagecontent,
        ImageBinary = @imagecontent
    WHERE imageID = (
            SELECT codeimg
            FROM Agent
            WHERE PPR = @ppr
            )
END
ELSE
    INSERT INTO ImageStorage (
        ImageName,
        ImageContentType,
        ImageBinary
        )
    VALUES (
        @imagename,
        @imagecontent,
        @imagebinary
        )

COMMIT
```

Thank you

Comment: Take a look here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: You may want to just do the update and check the [**@@ROWCOUNT**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) to decide to do the update.  I believe it will be less work on the server (right now you're querying to see if it exists anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert the image:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
     var binary = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(ms.GetBuffer());
}
```

pass "binary" to your method as "imagebinary" parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop your stored procedure from the designer and it will be available in your data context.

[From Microsoft:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384574.aspx)

> To create DataContext methods that return automatically generated
>   types
>
> 1. In **Server Explorer/Database Explorer**, expand the **Stored Procedures** node of the database you are working with.
> 2. Locate the desired stored procedure and drag it onto an empty area of the O/R Designer.
>
> The DataContext method is created with an automatically generated
>   return type and appears in the **Methods** pane.
>
> To create DataContext methods that have the return type of an entity
>   class
>
> 1. In **Server Explorer/Database Explorer**, expand the **Stored Procedures** node of the database you are working with.
> 2. Locate the desired stored procedure and drag it onto an existing entity class in the O/R Designer.
>
> The DataContext method is created with the return type of the selected
>   entity class and appears in the **Methods** pane.

---

Secondly consider changing your proc to this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uploadImage] @ppr INT,
    @imagename VARCHAR,
    @imagecontent VARCHAR,
    @imagebinary IMAGE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ImageStorage
    SET ImageName = @imagename,
        ImageContentType = @imagecontent,
        ImageBinary = @imagecontent
    WHERE @ppr IS NOT NULL
        AND imageID = (
            SELECT codeimg
            FROM Agent
            WHERE PPR = @ppr
            )

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO ImageStorage (
            ImageName,
            ImageContentType,
            ImageBinary
            )
        VALUES (
            @imagename,
            @imagecontent,
            @imagebinary
            )
END
```